# Icon generator to emulate Windows 7 folder with contents

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons

(*Note*: I didn't know how to properly word this question: improvements are welcome!)

I'm looking for an utility (whether desktop or online service) to create folder icons in the same way as Windows 7 does in Explorer.
I guess it is just easier to show it than describe it:

[image]

I mean: if one creates a folder and it only puts a picture file inside, then Explorer will change icon for that folder, showing the picture as if inserted between the two folds.

At the moment, I'm able to do something similar, starting from a GIMP document with distinct layers for both folds and their content, for each icon size.

Is there any tool available where you can just provide a picture, and it will be able to create folder icons for each size as Explorer does?

**EDIT** (after comments):
I'd like to obtain the same results with a tool, so that I can save results as an .ICO file, associate that with the folder, and be free to store what I want in that folder root.

Comment: In what siltation will you be using this? I mean, does Windows explorer's implementation not suffice for your needs? Or is this to just automatically create graphics for you?

Comment: I edited question after your comment. If I'm still not clear, please do ask.

Comment: Are you opposed to using custom images as the folder icon? So instead of having the 'open folder with X image' as the icon representing that folder just have 'X image' be the icon? Anecdote: I personally have different types of images and icons to represent my many folders; an atom icon represents my code folder, a building represents my main drive, etc. etc.

Comment: No, not always against that. But e.g. for a customer folder I'd like to use a folder icon with customer logo between folds, instead of the customer logo straight away. BTW a colleague of mine, in the same way as you do, uses *non-folder* icons for his typical folders (code, documents, ...)